# Не удается привязать файлы cookie в get запросе axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при отправке get запроса c помощью axios на сервер файлы cookie не привязываются

```js
axios.get(`https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/auth/me`, { withCredentials: true, })
```

```js
.then(res => console.log(res.data.data))
```

(в объекте находится объект) запрос возвращает пустой объект (по факту должен возвращать логин, emайл и идентификатор).

при вводе https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/auth/me в адресной строке браузера, выдается правильный объект. помогите, пожалуйста, не знаю, что делать

Comment: Для подобных запросов обычно используют `post` запрос

Comment: В документации к api написано, что это get запрос и он только возвращает response

Comment: Скорее всего нет каких-то параметров, вот ничего и не возвращает

Comment: Я поэтому и задал вопрос, потому что не могу найти, что я не добавил)

Comment: Прикрепите ссылку на документацию. Откуда ж мы узнает, чего там не хватает?)